# Limit access of base function to constructor of derived

Tags: c++

I have a base class that provides a method to create a SpecialType. This type needs to be registered by the Base class, so Base is the only type that is allowed to create SpecialType.
However, i want that derived classes are able to obtain such a type via a member function of Base. I want to limit this access to the constructor of Derived.

```
class SpecialType{
    friend class Base;
private:
    SpecialType() = default;
}

class Base{
protected:
    // registers that a SpecialType was created
    SpecialType createVerySpecialType();
}

class Derived: public Base{
    // this should be okay
    SpecialType mSpecial = createVerySpecialType();
    
    void memberFunction(){
        // this should be forbidden
        auto tmpSpecialType = createVerySpecialType();
    }

}
```

Is there a way to enforce a restriction like that to prevent potential wrong usage? If not, could you point out a better design to achieve something similar?

Comment: C++ doesn't have fine-grained control like that. Perhaps if you tell us *why* you need something like this, what the original and actual problem this is supposed to solve is, then we might be able to help you with that instead? Always please ask about the underlying and actual problem directly instead of showing us a "solution" to the unknown problem and ask us to help you fix it.

Comment: a way could be to use a factory function and grant only the factory access to constructor and the "special" type. THough, I second dude, one can come up with some way of doing what you ask for but without knowing why you think you need it, any solution might be improper for reasons you didnt tell us yet

Comment: `Dervied::memberFunction` can anyway do `Derived tmp; auto tmpSpecialType = std::move(tmp.mSpecial);`. The artificial restriction you are entertaining seems pointless to me.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik only if the type is movable.